# Running Powershell command in a command line/batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, command-line, scripting, sid

I am creating a batch file which involves converting a SID to local/domain username. Since we can not achieve this using the command prompt I am planning to use powershell and I have the PS command as well. I am able to run it in powershell console without any issue, but not sure how to use it in command prompt as a SINGLE LINE(to use it in batch file). I have already tried the below.

Powershell command which works perfectly in PS console -

```
([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]("S-1-5-32-544")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

Command lines which I have already tried but with no success -

```
powershell -command ([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]("S-1-5-32-544")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value

powershell -command {([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]("S-1-5-32-544")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it due to any escape characters or am I missing any powershell command parameters? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not write the entire script in PowerShell instead?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Thanks, but I am not good at powershell and my script is almost ready except this part. Only reason I need PS is to convert the SID to user and there is no way to do it in cmd.

Comment: What does your script do that requires the SID translation?

Comment: I'm writing a script that generates the access report of Visual SVN and Visual SVN stores the permissions in the form of "SID=read/write". I need to convert them to human readable report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
powershell -command "([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]('S-1-5-32-544')).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value"
```

worked for me. Just a question of changing the innermost double-quotes to singles around the SID.

Alternatively, escape them with a backslash

```
powershell -command "([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier](\"S-1-5-32-544\")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value"
```

Comment: Awesome, Both of them works. Thanks @andyb. I knew it was something to do with escaping characters. - Cheers, G

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short VBScript script that uses WMI to do the conversion for you:

```
Dim SID
SID = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

Dim SWbemServices, SWbemObject
Set SWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set SWbemObject = SWbemServices.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & SID & "'")
WScript.Echo SWbemObject.ReferencedDomainName & "\" & SWbemObject.AccountName
```

You would of course need to capture this script's output from your shell script (batch file).

Comment: Thanks @Bill_Stewart. I got my answer, but appreciate your help by providing alternate methods.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually really close.  What you want to do is this:

```
powershell -command "& {([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]('S-1-5-32-544')).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}"
```

I tested this using the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet.  In a standard, but elevated cmd shell I entered:

```
powershell -command "& {get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem}"
```

At that point the wmi object data as returned by powershell was written to the console.  You can also load the command into a variable like so:

```
set wmi=powershell -command "& {get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem}"
```

If you call the variable `%wmi%` there's a delay before it prints.  The command itself is in the variable so everytime you call the variable it'll execute the powershell code and return the result.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works fine if it is a simple/single PS command. But when it involves a big command with braces it gives trouble. I tried your suggestion, but it returns error. I will post the error in the next comment.

Comment: C:\>powershell -command "& {([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]("S-1-5-32-544")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}"
S-1-5-32-544 : The term 'S-1-5-32-544' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:52
+ & {([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier](S-1-5-32-544)).Translate([Sys ...
+

Comment: Yes Colyn, it is the PS error, But the same command works when executed in powershell console!

Comment: @gbabu experiment with using single quotes instead of doubles.

Comment: Different error with single quotes. I think this time cmd separates the command before and after '&' <br/>

The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: what happens if you don't use quotes around the SID?

Comment: Tried that as well, It gives the same error as i mentioned in my 2nd comment

Comment: Need single quotes around the SID. See my answer.

Comment: @andyb That's what I was suggesting when I advised you to use single quotes.  I even updated my answer at that time to use single quotes around the SID.

Comment: The edit time is documented and can be viewed.  It's clearly half a day before you posted your answer.

Comment: Sorry @Colyn1337. I read the comment chain and it looked like the issue was not answered (you suggested the OP 'experiment' with single quotes and then to try removing the quoutes around the SID). To me, this suggested you had not tested. I also noticed what appeared to be extraneous & and {} in your suggestion. I decided to test on my own. I copied OP code into PowerGUI and reproduced the error. Changed the quotes around the SID (a fairly obvious modification given the nature of command line parameter parsing) and got a working solution. I posted it as an answer. Was I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer is to use a base64 encodedcommand switch.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -encodedcommand "KABbAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAC4AUwBlAGMAdQByAGkAdAB5AC4AUAByAGkAbgBjAGkAcABhAGwALgBTAGUAYwB1AHIAaQB0AHkASQBkAGUAbgB0AGkAZgBpAGUAcgBdACgAIgBTAC0AMQAtADUALQAzADIALQA1ADQANAAiACkAKQAuAFQAcgBhAG4AcwBsAGEAdABlACgAWwBTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAuAFMAZQBjAHUAcgBpAHQAeQAuAFAAcgBpAG4AYwBpAHAAYQBsAC4ATgBUAEEAYwBjAG8AdQBuAHQAXQApAC4AVgBhAGwAdQBlAA=="
PAUSE
```

When decoded, you'll see it's the OP's original snippet (with the double quotes preserved).   Maybe overkill for the OP, but useful for dev's with larger scripts. Plus my original answer was identical to someone elses, so I had to edit.

> powershell.exe -EncodedCommand

```
Accepts a base-64-encoded string version of a command. Use this parameter
to submit commands to Windows PowerShell that require complex quotation
marks or curly braces.
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this. Thanks. Would you mind explaining how to encode a PS command?

Comment: sure, just type `powershell.exe /help`, base64 encoding example is the very last paragraph.  (it's like 4-5 lines of code, too big for a comment)

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. I may not be able to use it this time as I will need to iterate this through for loop to convert several SIDs to user name. But it will surely help me some day.